# Get the value from previous page php, sql

Tags: php, html, sql

I can't get the value of id from update.php and give to it another page which is update2.php

Here is the code of my update.php

```
<form method = "post" action = "update2.php ?id=".$row['0'].">
        <p class = "head">Update Account Basic Info</p>
        <p class = "form">
        <input type = "text" class = "name" name = "f_name" placeholder = "First Name">
        <input type = "text" class = "name" name = "l_name" placeholder = "Last Name">
        <br>
        <input type = "text" class = "other" name = "email" placeholder = "Email Address">
        <br>
        <input type = "numeric" class = "other" name = "mob_no" placeholder = "Mobile Number">
        <br></br>
        <input type = "submit" name = "save" value = "Update Account">
        </p>
</form>
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("dbfacebook", $con);

        $query = "SELECT id_no, f_name, l_name, email, mob_no FROM tblaccount WHERE id_no = '$_GET[id]'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<p class = 'sub'>Current Account Basic Info</p>";
            echo "<p class = 'form'>ID Number: ".$row['0']."<br>";
            echo "First Name: ".$row['1']."<br>";
            echo "Last Name: ".$row['2']."<br>";
            echo "Email: ".$row['3']."<br>";
            echo "Mobile Number: ".$row['4']."</p>";
        }   
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Here is my code of update2.php

```
<?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("dbfacebook", $con);
        echo $_GET['id'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE tblaccount SET f_name = '$_POST[f_name]', l_name = '$_POST[l_name]', email = '$_POST[email]', mob_no = '$_POST[mob_no]' WHERE id_no = '$_GET[id]'");

        echo "<h1>Account Updated</h1>";
        mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My problem is my $_GET[id] function in update2.php can't get the value of id_no in update.php

Answer (score -1):

You wont get the right result when you use

```
action = "update2.php ?id=".$row['0']."
```

because, `.$row['0'].` is not `php`.. It is just HTML..

Instead, you will have to use

```
action = "update2.php?id=<?php echo $row['0']; ?>"
```

**UPDATE**

Since you are getting `Undefined variable: row` error, it means that `$row` is null.

Thus, Move

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("dbfacebook", $con);

        $query = "SELECT id_no, f_name, l_name, email, mob_no FROM tblaccount WHERE id_no = '$_GET[id]'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

to the line before opening the `<form>`.

ie, Now, the code should be like

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("dbfacebook", $con);

        $query = "SELECT id_no, f_name, l_name, email, mob_no FROM tblaccount WHERE id_no = '$_GET[id]'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    <form method = "post" action = "update2.php?id=<?php echo $row['0']; ?>">
}

?>
```

Comment: it gives me this error Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\final\act2\update.php on line 8
">

Comment: That's not how string interpolation works in PHP. Arrays need to be escaped using curly braces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @TiesonT. Not mandatory...this is just another way to do it..You shouldn't have downvoted this as the answer suggested is correct and not an error..